# Jackson YAML Parser Deleted Special characters

Tags: jackson, yaml

I have issue while using ObjectMapper with YAMLFactory to Parse a YAML File

1. The YAML file I’m trying to parse  : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q85OmjH-IAIkordikLTsC1oQVTg8ggc8
2. Parsing the File using readValue as shown here :

   `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().enable(Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES)//
               .disable(Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER)//
               .disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.SPLIT_LINES));
       TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
       HashMap<String, Object> obj = mapper.readValue(responseBuffer.toString(), typeRef);`
3. Converting the Obj to json then to YAML again by :

   `JsonElement jsonElem = wrapJacksonObject(obj);
       String cloudTemplateJsonString = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().setPrettyPrinting()//
               .create()//
               .toJson(jsonElem);
       JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(cloudTemplateJsonString);
       String yaml = new YAMLMapper().enable(Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES)//
               .disable(Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER)//
               .writeValueAsString(jsonNode);`
4. After checking the last String, I see that these Special Characters are Changed/Deleted (they are Changed exactly after Point 2) :

   a.  ‘ transferred to “ or Deleted
   b.  ! : Regarding the exclamation mark : the whole string after it until first space is deleted totally

   Examples :

   ```
   Version: !Join ['-', [!Ref GatewayVersion, GW]]
   After Parsing  
   Version:
      - '-'
      - - GatewayVersion
      - GW
   ```

Also single Quotes sometimes Deleted / Converted to double Quote

```
 AllowedPattern: '^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})$'
```

After Parsing Single quotes Deleted :

```
 AllowedPattern: ^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})$
```

5. I try to use Escape Characters Customization By customizing Implementation for CharacterEscapes class but it didn’t help

Comment: After Debugging, i found that the issue with : 
`Object value = deserialize(p, ctxt);`
Inside Class : UntypedObjectDeserializer
when deserialize try to find the value, i see that the Parser has current token : !Ref
but the YAMLParser advanced to the next token and neglect it in a strange way
I'm talking about this line Number 648  JsonToken t = p.nextToken();
Inside deserialize Function
I need here some one expert with YamlParser to find where is the issue

Answer (score 1):

In YAML, a value such as a string literal can be prepended by tokens indicating metadata about the node, known as node properties. Tokens beginning with a bang `!` are considered to be 'node tags', and tokens begining with an ampersand `&` are 'node anchors'.

https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2783797

JSON does not have an equivalent capability. Because Jackson is primarily a JSON parsing library its internal representation of structured data nodes do not have fields for metadata, and so its YAMLFactory parser implementation simply discards them.

Looking at your YAML file I expect the intended parser of the file (aws' cloudwatch cli tool?) would have known how to use those !Join and !Ref node tags to construct an internal representation of the Version field.

Similarly, single or double quotes surrounding a text value are considered to be part of the markup (i.e., used the parser) rather than part of the value. Thus the parser discards these characters (after using them as guides on how to consume the value). Quotes (double or single) may be added or not as neccessary when reserializing an internal representation back into YAML or JSON.